# Why does a IIS hosted WCF service implemented with Castle Windsor require a base address?

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

I have a .NET 4.0 WCF service that's implemented with the Dependecy Injection pattern using Castle Windsor (v3). The service is hosted in IIS 7 and I use the Visual Studio Development Server when running locally. My dev server assigns a specific port to the service.

Now, if I don't add a base address I will get an exception from Castle Windsor saying:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

But, if I do assign a localhost address with the same port as my developer server, I get a port conflict.

Why do I need a base address in this case, and how do I handle the port conflict?

Here's my Castle Windsor-related code. The container is created in my Application_Start() in the Global.asax.cs file.

```
public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
            .Register(Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyService>().AsWcfService<IMyService>().IsDefault()
        );
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not interested in hosting several services, there's just one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer, credited Craig Neuwirt from the Castle Project Google Group.

> If it's being hosted in IIS you probably need to mark it as hosted so it should look something like
>
> ```
> container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>() 
> .Register(Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyService>().AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel().Hosted()).IsDefault()
> ```

And for the record, my configuration was set up as suggested by Sir Hally, and that's when the port conflict appeared. With the additional fluent configuration above, I removed the base address configuration from the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your config?

If you host your service on IIS, the base address depends on site, application and port (according to IIS binding for current protocol - net.tcp, http).

You can user Visual Studio Development Server for http-based services (not net.tcp).
You can specify base address in config for VS DevelopmentService (inside your `<service>` tag)

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MyApp/Service.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```